# Problem with python prepared stmt parameter passing

Tags: python, parameters, prepared-statement

File C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py, line 1149, in execute elif len(self._prepared[parameters]) != len(params): TypeError: object of type int has no len()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is python make error when we pass single parameter we need to put comma(,)
at the end of first parameter. like the follwoing

```
input=(customerId,)
cursor.execute(sql, input)
```